# How to read function definitions with get-command

Tags: .net, function, powershell, reference

I want to understand what the **TryGetValue** method of a **$PSBoundParameters** object is doing:

```
($PSBoundParameters | gm -Name trygetvalue).definition

bool TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value),
bool IDictionary[string,Object].TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value),
bool IReadOnlyDictionary[string,Object].TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value)
```

Not sure what I am seeing when looking at the methods definition.

Are these 3 different overloads I'm looking at?

What are example of how I would call it for each overload?

Comment: I don't quite know enough to write this as an answer, but the latter 2 definitions you see there are showing the definition of `TryGetValue` on the interfaces that `PSBoundParameterDictionary` implements. I don't believe they can be called directly, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there an MS doc that explains the format of these definitions as get-command displays the?

Comment: I tried to find something more concrete but couldn't. I'm almost certain it has to do with Interfaces and inheritance and such so I was trying to find info on that, but I was unsuccessful and I don't quite have the C# chops to explain it. It's likely you'll find the answer as it relates to C#; PowerShell's way of displaying it is probably based on that (or on reflection in general).